# Elixir Comprehension Efficiency

Tags: elixir

I have a large dataset that I am doing the following with:

```
data = %{
  city: ["Chiselhurst", "Saskatchewan", "Boston"],
  day: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  transportation: ["plane", "train", "automobile"]
}

defmodule Make do
  def combos(data) do
    for city <- data[:city],
        day <- data[:day],
        transportation <- data[:transportation] do
          List.flatten([city, day, transportation])
        end
  end

  def filter_map(data) do
    data
    |> Enum.filter_map(fn(x) -> x[:day] > 5 end, &(%{:trip => &1}))
  end

  def combos_filter(data) do
    data
    |> combos
    |> filter_map
  end
end
```

Is there any way to make the comprehension (`Make.combos`) more efficient?

Is there any way to filter asynchronously? I have been playing around with `Task.async` / `Task.await`, but haven't been able to use them with `Enum.filter`.

**UPDATE**

```
day_range = for n <- 1..5_000_000, do: n

data = %{
  city: ["Chiselhurst", "Saskatchewan", "Boston"],
  day: day_range,
  transportation: ["plane", "train", "automobile"]
}


defmodule Make do
  def combos(data) do
    for city <- data[:city],
        day <- data[:day],
        transportation <- data[:transportation] do
          [city, day, transportation]
        end
  end

  def combos_async(data) do
    chiselhurst = Task.async(fn -> partial_combos("Chiselhurst", data) end)
    saskatchewan = Task.async(fn -> partial_combos("Saskatchewan", data) end)
    boston = Task.async( fn -> partial_combos("Boston", data) end)

    Task.await(chiselhurst, 1000000) ++ Task.await(saskatchewan, 1000000) ++ Task.await(boston, 1000000)

  end

  defp partial_combos(city, data) do
    for day <- data[:day],
        transportation <- data[:transportation] do
          [city, day, transportation]
        end
  end

end
```

Comment: Approximately how many elements do you expect to have in each of the 3 lists in the actual dataset? The best place to add concurrency depends on that.

Comment: In the actual dataset there are 7 lists. 2 of the lists have thousands (sometimes millions of elements). The rest have less than 30.

Comment: And do you really want a list of list of 7 elements (in the 7 list case) at the end? I don't think running this on concurrently on different processes/Tasks would help at all if the end result you want is a huge list as the time taken to combine the results of each process/Task at the end will dwarf creating a list of 7 elements from 7 local values.

Comment: What about the current implementation you find inefficient?

Comment: have you considered filtering before running `combos`? It would reduce the amount of data that will be going throw `combos` and give you some efficiency.

Comment: @Dogbert - yes, I want a list of 7 element list.

Comment: @pdimitar - I don't necessarily think it's inefficient, I just want to know if there is a way to make it more efficient, I'm still pretty new to Elixir. See the update above - I was thinking something like that could speed up the function - initial benchmarking shows that it's making it slower (I guess combining the results is very expensive)

Comment: @jdesilvio Most likely the slowdown comes from the immutable nature of Elixir so you end up copying a lot (just a guess).

Did you benchmark both? I am using `benchwarmer`.

Comment: Yes, I am using `benchwarmer` too. Your explanation me sense if the copying is much more expensive than creating the combinations, which I assume it is.